# Why Android device does not take corresponding layout depends on mobile size in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created layouts within layout-large-port,layout-large-land,layout-normal-land,layout-normal-port,layout-small-port,layout-small-land folders. But my mobile does not pick up layout depends on their size.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

    private void setProfile()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.user_profile_layout);

    usersList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.users_list);
    usersList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    userProfilePic=((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.user_profile_pic_imageview));
    selectedUserName=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.selected_user_name));
    selectedUserName.setSelected(true);
    genderTextview=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.gender_textView));
    dobTextview=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.dob_textView));
    followsCountTextview=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.follows_count_textView));
    homeTownTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_profile_home_town_textview);

    selectedUserName.setText(new ManageSharedPreferences(UserProfileActivity.this).getUserName());
    Cursor cursor=new UpdateLocalDatabase().getUserProfile();
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if(cursor.getString(4).equals("male"))
        genderTextview.setText("Male");
    else
        genderTextview.setText("FeMale");

    dobTextview.setText(cursor.getString(3));
    homeTownTextView.setText(cursor.getString(5));

    if(ConstantValues.FAVORITE_STATIONS!=null)
        followsCountTextview.setText(""+ConstantValues.FAVORITE_STATIONS.size());

    bitmap=UserImageBitMap.getBitmap(new ManageSharedPreferences(UserProfileActivity.this).getUserID());
    userProfilePic.setImageBitmap(Functions.getRoundedRectBitmap(bitmap, 100));

    AsyncTaskCompletion asyncTaskCompletion=this;
    adapter=new StationListAdapter(UserProfileActivity.this, asyncTaskCompletion,null, ConstantValues.FAVORITE_STATIONS, false,usersList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    usersList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I mentioned above things in my manifest. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Remove android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize and test it , and however layout-large-port,layout-large-land,layout-normal-land,layout-normal-port,layout-small-port,layout-small-land are deprecated you have to use layout-sw320dp etc...

Comment: @user1283633 but I need that because I have using more web calls. Is there any other way to get.